# virt-manager network options or virtual network interfaces

Tags: network-interface, bridge, virt-manager, forwarding, macvlan

I want to ask about network options on virt-manager. I used to have the options shown in the given picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4SYR.jpg

```
host device eth0 : macvtap
host device wlan0 : macvtap
```

and I would see the `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces when I want to forward NAT to `eth0` in virt-manager when adding a new virtual network.

I'm on Debian 11 after installing `qemu` `kvm` `virt-manager` and the extras and everything related

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils libguestfs-tools genisoimage virtinst libosinfo-bin virt-manager libspice-client-glib-2.0 libspice-client-gtk-3.0 qemu-utils 
sudo adduser $USER libvirt-qemu
sudo adduser $USER libvirt
sudo modprobe macvtab macvlan
```

but still after restart, the `macvtap` options are not there whatever I do. Of course, I enabled `macvtab` in the kernel and even if I add it using:

```
ip link add link eth0 name macvtap0 type macvtap mode bridge/or vepa / or passthrough
```

still doesn't show.

`eth0` and `wlan0` options or other interfaces like `proton0` [created by ProtonVPN] or `tun0` created by OpenVPN do not show up when I try to create a new virtual network on `virt-manager` and forward NAT to any of these interfaces.

What's the problem here?

How can I get these options again?
[image]

Comment: What options do you get instead?

Comment: i only get host-nat and -the whonix ones- , but no macvtap or the ability to forward to eth0 or wlan0 , in fact eth0 and wlan0 don't even show up

Comment: Is that Debian 11 or Whonix? As I read Whonix runs Debian in a VM, that would not be the same.

Comment: So you have to [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/443543) your question and state what is your setup. If you're trying to get the real interfaces available in the VM that has only access through Tor to Internet (and very probably sees only layer 3 tunnel interfaces that don't allow macvlan) that's very different from running a normal Debian 11 running as normal (bare metal) system.

Comment: no , i have debian 11 , and i have whonix vms in debian 11 , the networks whonix external and internal are created by the whonix vms , i was just explaining that , but what i am interested in is the macvtap interfaces that won't show as an option in virt-manager in debian 11 , or even eth0 or wlan0 who don't show as options in virt-manager in debian 11.